# issue with text area nic editor data not update?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

i have facing some problems one is why i am getting 419 status error and then how can i send to controller multple data?

```
$(document).on( "click", '.submit',function(event) {
event.preventDefault();               
    var nicE = new nicEditors.findEditor('notes');
    var question = nicE.getContent();        
    var editid = $(this).attr('id');

      
    $('.test'+editid).hide();
    $('#test1'+editid).show();
    var formdata= new FormData($('#'+editid)[0]);
    var fileSelect = $("csvdocument").val();
    
    
     $.ajax({
           
           url:"updatenotes",
           type:"POST",
           data: {'formdata':formdata,'question':question, '_token': "$('input[name=_token]').val()"},
           enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
           contentType: false,
           cache: false,
           processData: false
           }).success(function(response)
           {

            alert('response');
            //location.reload();
            
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

[419 Status Code](https://markohoven.com/2018/01/23/419-http-status-code/) means, that you have didn't passed any CSRF token. Basically, Laravel configure [ajax default csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf) header using `bootstrap.js` file in your **resources** directory, so check if it's not commented/removed. It should look like this:

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

In second, check your *meta tags* in your *head* section of your blade template, It should containt something like this.

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

After that, remove `_token` input from your request body, and your issue should be solved.